# Any way to move elements without using margin propierty

Tags: html, css

I made a little survey project. To make it look a bit better i wanted to have a bit of space between the container and the text i put. I used the element margin but it's repeated like 20 times. Is there any other way to do it faster? Or is this the only way? This is the code i made i add the html file and the css.

```css
.container{   width: 100%;   margin: 3.125rem auto 0 auto;   max-width: 720px;}
header{  text-align: center; background-color: #005C69;  margin:auto;}
main{ font-size: 20px;}
body{   background-color: #0B0014;}
#survey-form{   box-sizing: border-box;   background-color: #005C69}

#name{display: block;width: 70%;height: 1.75rem;padding: 0.250rem 0.75rem;color: #495057;background-color: #fff;background-clip: padding-box;border: 1px solid #ced4da;border-radius: 0.25rem;margin-left: 17px;}
#email{display: block;width: 70%;height: 1.75rem;padding: 0.250rem 0.75rem;color: #495057;background-color: #fff;background-clip: padding-box;border: 1px solid #ced4da;border-radius: 0.25rem;margin-left: 17px;}
#number{display: block;width: 70%;height: 1.75rem;padding: 0.250rem 0.75rem;color: #495057;background-color: #fff;background-clip: padding-box;border: 1px solid #ced4da;border-radius: 0.25rem;margin-left: 17px;}
} 
#name-label{margin-left: 17px;}
#email-label{margin-left: 17px;}
#number-label{margin-left: 17px;}
#dropdown{ display: block;width: 40%;height: 1.75rem;padding: 0.250rem 0.75rem;color: #495057;background-color: #fff;background-clip: padding-box;border: 1px solid #ced4da;border-radius: 0.25rem;margin-left: 17px;}
#role{ margin-left: 17px;}
#radiop{ margin-left: 17px;}

.input-radio{margin-left: 17px;}
#first{margin-left: 17px;}
#second{margin-left: 17px;}
#third{ margin-left: 17px;}
#fourth{ margin-left: 17px;}
#fifth{   margin-left: 17px;}
#sixth{  margin-left: 17px;}
#seven{  margin-left: 17px;}
#eight{   margin-left: 17px;}
#changes{margin-left: 17px;}
#cat{margin-left: 17px;}
#textarea{min-height: 120px;width: 80%;padding: 0.625rem;resize: vertical;margin-left: 17px;}
.submit-button{display: block;width: 100%;padding: 0.75rem;background: #005C69;color: inherit;border-radius: 2px;cursor: pointer;color: red;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Survey form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<div class="container">
<header><h1 id="title">Survey to improve interface</h1><p id="description">Thank you for helping us to improve our services</p></header>
<body>
    <main>
    <form id="survey-form">
        <label for="name" id="name-label">Name</label><br>
        <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required=""> <br>
        <label for="email" id="email-label">Email</label><br>
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required=""> <br>
        <label for="age" id="number-label">Age</label><br>
        <input type="number" name="age" min="10" max="99" id="number" placeholder="Age"> <br>
        <label for="dropdown" id="role">Which option describes your current role?</label><br>
        <select name="recommend" id="dropdown"> <br>
        <option value="select">Select an option</option>
        <option value="student">Student</option>
        <option value="fullwork">Working full time</option>
        <option value="partwork">Working part-time</option>
        <option value="solowork">Self-Employed</option>
        <option value="nowork">Not working</option>
        </select>
        <p id=radiop>Would you recommend us?</p>
        <label>
        <input class="input-radio" type="radio" name="user-recommend" value="Definitely">
        Definitely <br>
        </label>
        <label>
        <input class="input-radio" type="radio" name="user-recommend" value="Maybe">
        Maybe <br>
        </label>
        <label>
        <input class="input-radio" type="radio" name="user-recommend" value="not-sure">
        Not sure <br>
        </label>
        <p id="changes">What would you improve?</p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="first" name="front-end" value="front">
        <label for="vehicle1">Front End Projects</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="second" name="back-end" value="back">
        <label for="vehicle1">Back End Projects</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="third" name="challenges" value="challenge">
        <label for="vehicle1">Challenges</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fourth" name="wiki" value="info">
        <label for="vehicle1">Our wiki</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fifth" name="forum" value="forum2">
        <label for="vehicle1">The forum</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sixth" name="videos" value="videos2">
        <label for="vehicle1">Videos/label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="seven" name="community" value="people">
        <label for="vehicle1">Community</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="eight" name="courses" value="courses2">
        <label for="vehicle1">Courses</label><br>
        <p id="cat">Any comments or suggestions?</p><br>
        <textarea name="text" id="textarea" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
        <button id="submit" class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button><br>
    </form>
</main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look into CSS classes

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, you can select all elements of a specific type at once. Only use classes and id's to target specific elements.

```css
input {
  margin-left: 17px;
}
```

You target inputs specifically by giving them a certain class:

```css
.some-class {
  margin-left: 17px;
}
```

You can even select input elements of a specific type like so:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  margin-left: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put all elements in the same class and make the css once. `.classForAll{ margin-left: 17px; }`